# Python Assign values to new dataframe like a schedule based on multiple conditions from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I started with this dataframe that had 4 columns: Name, Hours, Start Date and End Date:

| Name | Hours | Start Date | End Date | Total Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ashley | 6 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Bob | 8 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| John | 5 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| Chris | 5 | 4 | 4 | 1 |

Where 1-5 in the Start Date and End Date columns correspond to Monday-Friday.
I need to output a new dataframe/table that looks like this:

| Name | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ashley | 6 | 6 |  |  |  |
| Bob | 8 | 8 |  |  |  |
| John |  |  | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| Chris |  |  |  | 5 |  |

I figured I’d make a dictionary to map 1 thru 5 to M thru F.
I then calculated the 4th column, "Total Days", thinking maybe I could first map the respective hours to the Starting Date and then use the total days values to have it iterate that many columns after, but I’m totally lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all durations occur within the same week (this will not work beyond a single week without adding a modulus to keep cumcount from rolling over).

One option is to scale up the DataFrame based on `Total Days` with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html#pandas-index-repeat) and offset by [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount):

```
new_df = (
    df.drop(['End Date', 'Total Days'], 1)
        .loc[df.index.repeat(df['Total Days'])]
)
new_df['Start Date'] = new_df['Start Date'] + new_df.groupby('Name').cumcount()
```

```
     Name  Hours  Start Date
0  Ashley      6           1
0  Ashley      6           2
1     Bob      8           1
1     Bob      8           2
2    John      5           3
2    John      5           4
2    John      5           5
3   Chris      5           4
```

Then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot-table) and rename with values from [`calendar.day_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.day_name):

```
new_df = (
    new_df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Start Date',
                       values='Hours', aggfunc='sum')
        .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(calendar.day_name, 1)))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
     Name  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
0  Ashley     6.0      6.0        NaN       NaN     NaN
1     Bob     8.0      8.0        NaN       NaN     NaN
2   Chris     NaN      NaN        NaN       5.0     NaN
3    John     NaN      NaN        5.0       5.0     5.0
```

---

All together:

```
import calendar

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': {0: 'Ashley', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'John', 3: 'Chris'},
    'Hours': {0: 6, 1: 8, 2: 5, 3: 5},
    'Start Date': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4},
    'End Date': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 4},
    'Total Days': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1}
})

new_df = (
    df.drop(['End Date', 'Total Days'], 1)
        .loc[df.index.repeat(df['Total Days'])]
)
new_df['Start Date'] = new_df['Start Date'] + new_df.groupby('Name').cumcount()

new_df = (
    new_df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Start Date',
                       values='Hours', aggfunc='sum')
        .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(calendar.day_name, 1)))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's try:

```
import calendar
df['days'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.arange(x['Start Date'], x['End Date']+1), axis=1)
dfe = df.explode('days')
df_out = dfe.pivot_table('Hours', 'Name', 'days', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)\
            .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(calendar.day_name, 1)))
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
days    Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
Name                                                
Ashley       6        6          0         0       0
Bob          8        8          0         0       0
Chris        0        0          0         5       0
John         0        0          5         5       5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way with dummies:

```
w = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
d = dict(enumerate(w,1))
a = ['|'.join(map(d.get,range(a,b+1))) for a,b in zip(df['Start Date'],df['End Date'])]

out = df[['Name']].join(pd.Series(a).str.get_dummies()
        .mul(df['Hours'],axis=0).reindex(d.values(),axis=1).dropna(how='all',axis=1))
```

---

```
print(out)

     Name  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
0  Ashley       6        6          0         0       0
1     Bob       8        8          0         0       0
2    John       0        0          5         5       5
3   Chris       0        0          0         5       0
```